# Implementing an abstract, generic Java class with abstract member class in Scala

Tags: java, scala, generics, overriding

I'm trying to implement an abstract, generic Java class in Scala, and I'm getting an error of the form

```
object creation impossible, since method B in class A of type (x$1: A<Concrete1, Concrete2>#C)Unit is not defined
```

The library classes that I'm implementing look like this:

```java
public abstract class A<T, U> {
    public void B(C);

    public abstract class C {
        // elided
    }
}
```

and I want to implement an `A` to hand back to the library (which will call `B`, supplying a `C`). In Java, I can do:

```java
new A<Concrete1, Concrete2>() {
    @Override
    public void B(C c) {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

In Scala, I'm trying

```scala
new A[Concrete1, Concrete2] {
    def B(c: C): Unit = {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

and I get the error message at the top. Using `override`, the compiler complains that `method B overrides nothing`. It seems that the Scala type system isn't recognizing the `C` I pass in as an `A<Concrete1, Concrete2>#C`, but I'm not sure what type it *does* think it is.

I've tried specifying `self: A[Concrete1, Concrete2] =>`, as well as a self-type on `C`: `def B(c: self.C`, but neither solves the problem. I also tried `def B(c: A[Concrete1, Concrete2].C)`, but this raises a syntax error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: `def B(c: A[Concrete1, Concrete2]#C): Unit`. Needed the generic type information for this to be a valid override, but I wasn't aware of the `#` operator.